# Passing parent to child in constructor

Tags: javascript

Given the following objects:

```
Parent = (function() {
  function Parent(child) {
    this.child = child;
  }
  return Parent;
})();

Child = (function() {
  function Child(name, parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  return Child;
})();
```

Is there a way to create a parent and child in one statement? (with the child having a proper reference to the parent)

Sort of like this:

```
var parent = new Parent(new Child("john", thisThatPointsToTheNewParent));
```

This is just to show what I'm after. I know I can create the child and parent separately and then update the child's reference later but in my case it would be WAY easier if I could do it in one shot. Is there a way?

Comment: Try creating them separately an you'll see the flaw in your design.

Comment: This looks like an attempt at inheritance gone wrong...What are you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: I'm creating an array of Parent on the fly to use as data on a page. I do this by concatenating a string "new Parent(...)," on the controller. After writing this comment I think I can do without the reference but I'd still like to know if it's possible, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you'll end up with circular reference because the Child referencing to Parent and Parent referencing to Child.  This is one way to achieve the one-liner you were looking for:

```
var Parent = function (name, referenceToChild) {
    function Parent(name, child) {
        this.name = name;
        this.child = child;
        child.parent = this;
        return this;
    }
    return new Parent(name, referenceToChild);
};

var Child = function (name) {
    function Child(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
        return this;
    };
    return new Child(name);
};

var parent = new Parent("Tom", new Child("john"));
```

Ends up with:

```
{                            // Parent
 name: "Tom",
 child: {                    // Child
     name: "john",
     parent: {               // Parent
         name: "Tom",
         child: {            // Child
             name: "john",
             parent: {       // Parent
                 ....
```